# Do I need T&& and std::forward when writing a templated `<<` operator?

Tags: c++, c++11, perfect-forwarding

I'm writing a class which is meant to be used like `MyClass() << "some args here" << ...;` and forwards these values to a regular `ostream` that it holds internally.

This seems to work:

```
class MyClass {
    std::ostringstream oss;

public:
    template<typename T>
    MyClass& operator<<(T&& val) {
        oss << std::forward<T>(val);
        return *this;
    }
    ~MyClass() {
        std::cout << "Final result: " << oss.str() << std::endl;
    }
};
```

I used `T&&` and `std::forward<T>` because I'm used to seeing them with [perfect forwarding](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/perfect-forwarding-and-universal-references-in-c).

However, this works too:

```
template<typename T>
MyClass& operator<<(T val) {
    oss << val;
    return *this;
}
```

So is the "perfect forwarding" actually necessary? I wasn't able to construct a counterexample for the simplified version, no matter whether the available `operator<<` for T takes it by value or by reference.

Comment: Yes, it's necessary, in order to avoid making unneeded duplicate copies of objects. It is also needed for objects that do not have a default copy constructor.

Comment: I understand why `operator<<(ostream&, const Foo&)` would be needed for those cases, but does that actually necessitate `T&&` and `std::forward` in my class? Couldn't `T` just bind to `const Foo&`?

Comment: No, it won't bind.

Comment: But this works: http://ideone.com/yRtlKr

Comment: You missed the "do not have a default copy constructor part". Now, add some instrumentation, and watch a bunch useless object copies taking place.

Comment: Ah yes, I see, updated: http://ideone.com/yRtlKr

Comment: since `ostream` does not change it's parameter, `const T&` will work just as fine

Comment: Your second version will fail to compile if `T` does not have an accessible copy-constructor nor a move-constructor